# view pdf stored on public/storage on laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, download

My code doesn't save pdf's, I need to show it. If it's possible download it too.

```
<td><a name="Manual" href="{{asset('storage/app').'/'.$machineData->getManual()}}">
                Manual de {{$machineData->getMachineName()}}</a></td>
```

On controller I have this

```
protected function downloadFile($src)
{
    if(is_file($src))
    {
        $finfo=finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $content_type=finfo_file($finfo,$src);
        finfo_open($finfo);
        $file_name=basename($src).PHP_EOL;
        $size=filesize($src);
        header("Content-Type: $content_type");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-Length: $size");
       
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
public function download(Request $request)
{
    $note=$request->file('manual');
    if(!$this->downloadFile(app_path(). $note))
    {
        return redirect("/machineIndex");
       
    }

}
```

Please help, I just want to show the file, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve this with TCPDF

```
        $pdf = new TCPDF('P', 'in', [$sizeX, $sizeY], true, 'UTF-8', false);

        $pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
        $pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->SetMargins(0, 0, 0, true);
        $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);

        $pdf->Output($outputPath, 'I');
```

This code would create a new pdf document, then have a look at https://tcpdf.org/ to make the necessary changes and the  `$pdf->Output($outputPath, 'I');` at the end will open the pdf without saving it to storage (almost like a dd).

---

Edit:

I wrote this with the assumption that you didn't want to save the file to storage, if the file is already saved in public/storage you can present it with a direct url to it.
You would need the symlink with `php artisan storage:link` then guide to where it is in the directory. For example 'laravel.test/public/pdfs/pdf1.pdf'

More info on https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem